# Is this mapping group homomorphism? (topological groups)

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let's $f:G\to R$, where G is topological group. We denote by Mg group of all real valued functions on G.Fix $a \in G$. We define $f_a(x):=f(ax)$ for all $x \in G$

Now define $h_a(f):=f_a$ we know that $h_a:Mg \to Mg$.
Define $\varphi(a):=h_a$ We know, that this is isometry, then denote group of all isometries of space Mg into itself by Is(Mg).
I should show that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism of groups Mg and Is(Mg).
But probably throught great number of signs i have had only bad ideas.
Please help.

Comment: Seems I'm messing things up as well: Unrolling the definitions, $\phi(ab)(f)$ is a function hat maps $x\mapsto f(abx)$, whereas $\phi(a)(\phi(b)(f))$ is a function that maps $x\mapsto (\phi(b)(f))(ax)=f(bax)$.

Comment: Could you develop second thing please? My idea is: $(\varphi(a) \circ\varphi(b))(f)(x)=(h_a \circ h_b)(f)(x)=h_a(h_b(f))(x)=h_a(f_b)(x)=h_a(f)(bx)=f_a(bx)=f(abx)$